# ListView not showing when called from a different thread

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I'm trying to show a ListView from a different thread, but not sure what I'm missing here. This is the handleMessage() approach, I've also tried to create a timer and runOnUiThread() scheme, but that also fails to display anything. I know for sure that there is no issue with the listview itself since if I just call this entire activity again, it'll work (but, don't want to use that design). Would appreciate any tips...

```
public void ShowList(String[] list)
{
    for (String val : list)
        Log.d(TAG, "ShowList: list = " +val);

    // Set up the list view
    GuideAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, android.R.id.list, list);

    setListAdapter(GuideAdapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "ShowList: Created setListAdapter...");

    // Get an object for the list
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setCacheColorHint(0);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
        }
    });
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()
{
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.what == STATE_GUIDE) {              
        ShowList(ChannelList);
        }

    return true;
    }
});

public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public MyThread()   {
    }

    public void run()   {
        ...
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(STATE_GUIDE, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sharing the getListView() method would help in debugging Also, if this is run within a thread, why is an adapter being created each time....you should reference the adapter, the list content, notify the data set has changed, etc.

Comment: @drunkenRabbit, thanks for your response. Sorry, I'm a newbie at this. I don't have the getListView() method. Should I implement that? If so, could you please point me to some example?

Answer (score 0):

Change following code

```
// Set up the list view
GuideAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, android.R.id.list, list);
```

to following

```
// Set up the list view
GuideAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.list, list);
```

And don't call ShowList(ChannelList); on your Handler. Call it on onCreate method. Since ArrayAdapter cannot be called more then one time in single activity.

Comment: I just realized that the threading part is ok, but I have a problem with the UI, will post a new question

Comment: With some changes, I'm now able to see the ListView but can't select anything since the control is going to the activity that is hosting the VideoView & the setOnItemClickListener is in the main activity. Maybe the solution is move the ListView handling to the 2nd activity (the one that holds the VideoView)?